# How to copy templates folder into build folder automatically in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

In my project I have `application/` folder and `build/` folder with client files (CoffeeScript files and Mustache templates).

In PhpStorm I added watcher for CoffeeScript files; they compiled automatically on file change. But also I have `templates/` folder with Mustache templates in it and these files do not copy automatically.

How to set up PhpStorm to copy these files from `templates` folder into `build` (without any compilation or something)?

Comment: Gulp/Grunt/Phing task; npm script; simple external tools entry (batch/shell script)

Comment: Thanks, I used batch script (in Windows).